# In angular some plugins stop working if they have the property display: none;

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know if someone has happened, that has elements that use libraries that normally work. If from the beginning I applied

```
display: none
```

, when I make the hidden element appear

```
display:inline-block;
```

, the behavior of this varies or simply no longer work.

A recent example is with this library, it works normal but if by default it starts to be hidden, it does not work well.

```
Https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-swiper
```

Comment: Which library are you ta;king about..Probably a link to the library and some of your code would make things clear

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-swiper